# Aumentar tamaño de grafica con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

estoy graficando figuras geometricas, pero necesitaria aumentar el tamaño de la grafica de salida, como lo hago?[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aqui el codigo

Comment: Sugiero que se ponga el código en texto para facilitar su revisión, esto favorecerá  tus chances de obtener buenas respuestas.

Answer (score 1):

Si lo que necesitas es aumentar el tamaño del grafico lo podes hacer con figsize.
Mira un ejemplo:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
### Aca definis el tamaño
plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
x = [1,2,3]
plt.plot(x, x)
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]